# Update de uma query de forma parcelar

Tags: sql, node.js, postgresql

Boas tardes, hoje surgiu-me uma pequena duvida. Em algures no meu código tenho uma query para fazer um update. 
A função é a seguinte:

```js
function updateUser(user_id, params) {
    const query = `UPDATE users 
                   SET user_name = $1,
                       user_brithday = $2,
                       user_active = $3
                   WHERE user_id = $4`;
    const queryParams = [
        params.user_name,
        params.user_brithday,
        params.user_ative,
        user_id
    ];

    return pg.query(query, queryParams);
}
```

O que pretendia era por exemplo se enviar o object params sem algumas chaves, não fazer o update para undefined mas sim preservar o que já se encontra lá.
Já vi que é possível se gerar dinamicamente a query mas o que queria era saber se existe alguma forma na query de fazer isso.

Answer (score 1):

Se o que queres fazer é montar uma `query` dinamicamente com apenas as colunas informadas no objeto, faça o seguinte:

Defina uma variável para armazenar a quantidade de parâmetros, e o objeto que irá armazenar os valores da query:

```
let total = 1;
let queryParams = [];
```

Defina a variável `query` com o valor inicial:

```
let query = `UPDATE users SET `;
```

Crie um laço `for` para percorrer o objeto `params`, dentro dele, verifique se o valor de `total` é maior que 1, se for maior, a cada loop concatena uma virgula e a chave na `query`.

```
if (total > 1) { query += `, `; }
query += `${key} = $${total}`;
```

Depois adicione o valor da chave no objeto `queryParams`;

```
queryParams.push(params[key]);
```

Faça o incremento na variável `total`:

```
total++;
```

O laço completo:

```
for (key in params){
  if (total > 1) { query += `, `; }
  query += `${key} = $${total}`;
  queryParams.push(params[key]);
  total++;
}
```

Para finalizar, concatene a clausula `WHERE` na `query` e adicione o parâmetro `user_id` no objeto `queryParams`:

```
query += ` WHERE user_id = $${total}`;
queryParams.push(user_id);
```

#### Exemplo funcionando

```js
function updateUser(user_id, params) {
  let total = 1;
  let queryParams = [];
  let query = `UPDATE users SET `;
  for (key in params){
    if (total > 1) { query += `, `; }
    query += `${key} = $${total}`;
    queryParams.push(params[key]);
    total++;
  }
  query += ` WHERE user_id = $${total}`;
  queryParams.push(user_id);
  console.log(query);
  console.log(queryParams);
  // return pg.query(query, queryParams);
}

updateUser(1, { user_name: 'Usuário 1', user_brithday: '1960-05-30' });
updateUser(2, { user_brithday: '1990-11-12' });
```